# Unnest two columns with Redshift Spectrum

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have this table called results, with two nested arrays in columns students and grades:

| class | students | grades |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | [S1, S2, S3] | [C, A, B] |
| C2 | [S3, S4] | [A, B] |

I'd like to unnest it to the following:

| class | student | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | S1 | C |
| C1 | S2 | A |
| C1 | S3 | B |
| C2 | S3 | A |
| C2 | S4 | B |

I tried the following request in Redshift, but it creates duplicates and the results is not correct:

```
SELECT class, student as s, grade as g
FROM spectrum.results r
LEFT JOIN r.students s ON true
LEFT JOIN r.grades g ON true;
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **UNNEST** both column together.

```sql
WITH dataset (class, students, grades) AS (
    VALUES ('C1', array['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], array['C', 'A', 'B']),
     ('C2', array['S3', 'S4'], array['A', 'B'])
) 
select class,
   T.students,
   T.grades
from dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (students, grades) T (students, grades)
ORDER BY class, students, grades
```

**OUTPUT**

| class | student | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | S1 | C |
| C1 | S2 | A |
| C1 | S3 | B |
| C2 | S3 | A |
| C2 | S4 | B |